# Thread target function's return does not cause thread to exit

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a simple thread that looks (simplified) like this:

```
import threading
import time

def print_coordinates():
    return

listener = threading.Thread(name = "listener", target = print_coordinates)

while(1):
    listener.start()
    time.sleep(1)
    listener.start()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Now, I receive the error `RuntimeError: threads can only be started once`. As far as I understood, `return` should cause the thread to "silently exit", as mentioned [here](https://www.python-course.eu/threads.php). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: yes, so the thread is dead and you need to spam one more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you cannot call `start` more than once.

See here:
http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.start

> It must be called at most once per thread object. It arranges for the
>   object’s run() method to be invoked in a separate thread of control.
>
> This method will raise a RuntimeError if called more than once on the
>   same thread object.

To call it once more, you will have to create another instance of that thread.

Comment: I thought that when the target function returns, the thread is closed and I could start a "new" one.

Comment: @mneumann, yes, but for the instance `listener`, you cannot call `start` more than once.

Comment: any idea how i would create a thread that loops over a potentially blocking function? i want this thread to exit on `SIGINT`. `join()` won't work since it waits for the thread to close, which it might never do.

Comment: You can't deliver a signal to a non-main thread.  There are other ways to communicate with threads but if the thread is blocked for an arbitrary amount of time in a syscall then you're probably out of luck.  However, this is too complex an issue to discuss in comments on an answer.